# Prevent input during a process in Windows-Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

I have a Window Mobile app where the forms use keypreview and post the form when the Enter key is pressed.  If the form post has a delay, the user may press enter again.  The second enter is processed when the first process ends.

How can I ignore the second enter press or prevent it from being queued?

I tried turning off keypreview, but the results were not consistent and the enter key was still processed by the control with focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498609/handle-windows-mobile-click-event-so-that-it-doesnt-queue-while-my-program-is) is probably the same problem (and the answers are the resolution).